# form_for submitting as PostsController#show instead of create when creating comments(nested)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, partials

I'm trying to figure out why my form is submitting wrong. I'm trying to implement nested comments under posts and my form renders but submits to the wrong action. I've tried a few things but cannot get it to work. I can create a comment via the rails console but not through my form. I was going through a railscast where he uses a older version of rails. I figured the main difference would be strong parameters but it doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out what I'm missing here. Thanks.

This is my log

```
Started GET "/posts/1?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=PJmmRV6hnY%2Bgm4cVe5LSdALHezbI3ehMkud0yYTaA%2FQ%3D&comment%5Bname%5D=Mark&comment%5Bemail%5D=hustada80%40gmail.com&comment%5Bcontent%5D=this+is+a+comment&commit=Create+Comment" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-08 14:34:53 -0500
Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PJmmRV6hnY+gm4cVe5LSdALHezbI3ehMkud0yYTaA/Q=", "comment"=>{"name"=>"Mark", "email"=>"hustada80@gmail.com", "content"=>"this is a comment"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment", "id"=>"1"}
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered comments/_form.html.erb (4.2ms)
  Rendered comments/_comments.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered posts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (53.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 524ms (Views: 519.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Here is my form ( a partial _form)

```
<div class="well">

    <h4>Leave a comment</h4>

  <form role="form" class="clearfix">

<%= form_for([@commentable, @comment]) do |f| %>
 <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Posts controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @post
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def index
    @post = Post.all
    @posts = Post.order('created_at DESC')
    ##@posts_by_month = Post.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC').group_by { |post| post.created_at.strftime("%B %Y") }
  end


  def month_count
    @posts_by_month = Post.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC').group_by { |post| post.created_at.strftime("%B %Y") }
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  end

  private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end
```

Comments Controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_commentable


  def index
    @comments = @commentable.comments
  end

  def new
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new
  end

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comments_params)
      if @comment.save
        redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment created."
      else
        render :new
      end
  end

  def destroy
  end




  private

  # def load_commentable
  #   resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
  #   @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
  # end

  def load_commentable
    klass = [Post].detect { |c| params["#{c.name.underscore}_id"]}
    @commentable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"])
  end


  def comments_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :email, :name)
  end
```

end

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root 'posts#index'
get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"
get "/log-in" => "sessions#new"
post "/log-in" => "sessions#create"
get "/log-out" => "sessions#destroy", as: :log_out


resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
resources :users
resources :sessions
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
<%= form_for([@commentable, @comment], url: post_comments_path, method: :post) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still getting the same behavior however.